# Does force:recordView work with Knowledge Articles?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili

I am trying to embed in a lightning component, the content of a knowledge article, through the [force:recordView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm) standard tag. As in the description doesn't state any restriction on the type of SObjects that it might be used, I wanted to know what are the limits here.

Apparently there should be one, as I tried to embed the component in an Article Layout in a Community using Napili Template, and I got:

> Invalid Record Id or Record not accessible

Anyone of you has come around this issue too?

Comment: What Id are you placing ?

Comment: An id of a Knowledge Article, as described above. I have created 2 Article Types. For one of those article types, I have created a record, that I can access through my Community. Inside the article detail community page I have placed a Lightning Component, that takes as an Input the Article Id, and shows the data of the article, through force:recordView tag. Hopes it's more clear now!